# No wireless networks detected in 14.04 after reboot

Tags: wireless, kernel, iwlwifi

I have a new Dell XPS 13 developer edition with 14.04. There have been no issues for the first few weeks, but after rebooting my computer yesterday I no longer detect wireless networks. How can I get it to work again?

Here are a few things I've done after googling this problem.

`lshw -C network` gives:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
      description: Network controller
      product: Wireless 8260
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
      version: 3a
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
      configuration: latency=0
      resources: memory:dc200000-dc201fff
```

`iwconfig` gives

```
    lo        no wireless extensions.
    eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`nm-tool` clearly detect the wired connection but doesn't mention anything about wireless connections.

I've run the wireless info script in the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos). The output is [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/22453923/).

What happened? Why did it suddenly stop working and why is it not working now? What does it mean that the network is "unclaimed"?

EDIT: Output from `dkms status` as requested:

```
~$ dkms status
btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260, 1.7, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260, 1.7, 3.19.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
intel-hid, 2.0, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
intel-hid, 2.0, 3.19.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-vivid, 0.201512022217~ubuntu14.04.1, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-vivid, 0.201512022217~ubuntu14.04.1, 3.19.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-rts-cr, 1.4.3oem2, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-rts-cr, 1.4.3oem2, 3.19.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
synaptic-i2c-hid-3.13.0-32-backport, 1.6.4: added
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dkms status` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I actually already solved my own problem.  Do you know why disabling secure boot fixed it?

Comment: I will tell you when you post the output.

Comment: It looks like you installed lots of custom modules. They do not work any more. I suggest removing them all.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this worked, but rebooting and disabling secure boot completely solved my problem. I found the solution somewhere else.

Can someone explain to me why disabling secure boot fixed this for me?

Comment: You installed a custom kernel module that does not work with Secure Boot any more.

Answer (score 0):

You installed a custom kernel DKMS module `btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260`.

The latest Ubuntu kernels do not load 3rd party kernel modules that are not signed if Secure Boot is enabled. You can see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules) for more details.

Kernel 3.19 should support this adapter now without any custom module, but I am not 100% sure, because I did not test it.

I am quite sure that the 4.4 kernel does support this adapter out of the box. This kernel is available from the official repositories for Ubuntu 14.04.

You can remove the `btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260` by this command:

```
sudo dkms remove btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260/1.7 --all
```

and see if Wi-Fi work after reboot.

If it does, you can enable Secure Boot and it will keep working with the updated in-tree module.

If it does not, you can always upgrade the kernel by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

With this kernel Intel 8260 will work with Secure Boot on for sure.